# Is there any possibility of divide-by-zero in this conditional statement?

Tags: c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, divide-by-zero

This is tricking my mind a little bit, because i can't seem to find any problem with this code.

Anyways, here's the riddle:

Suppose someone injects a random value into `a, b`:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return b ? (a / b): 0;
}
```

`b != 0` always!

Is it possible for an integer zero division exception to occur?

I'm starting to think this is a prank, yet....

NOTE:

This question was published in a conference, there is a possibility that the author was specific to a compiler/architecture where this is problematic.

Comment: `b != 0 always!` is given (guaranteed) or you need to enforce?

Comment: So a random value can be any value except zero?!

Comment: @SouravGhosh guaranteed. 'b' cannot be zero.

Comment: Do you interpret "injecting a random value into a, b" as passing random values to the function parameters a, b? Or shall injecting a value mean: changing a variable's value while the function is executing? With a debugger one could possibly do the second and provoke an integer zero division (b would have to be set to zero in this case).

Comment: Note that `INT_MIN/-1` could occur and is a different problem.

Comment: If you talk about "injection", there is no way to catch that before executing the division is ececuted. Note that it is better to use a (application level) trap representation representation (caught by the caller) or MIN/MAX if the divisor is `0`. That is more consistent.

Answer (score 4):

No, divide by zero is not possible here.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.15, *Conditional operator* , (*emphasis mine*)

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand **(whichever is evaluated). The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0**; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; [...]

So, in case, `b` is 0, the expression `(a/b)` will not be evaluated.

That said, just as note:

- The division is integer division.
- If you have a wrapper, that ensures `b != 0`, then you could cut down the whole function call and simply write `someVar = a/b;`

Also, I don't know of any architecture which (*possibly*) changes the aforesaid behavior.

Comment: I read the standard, but this is a question someone asked in a conference. maybe he was very specific, i mean, a specific compiler/architecture where this is problematic.

Comment: @Medals then you should mention that in your question, right?

Comment: @Medals: Context! If thjat is about flipped bits/corruption, this is useless, even potentially harmful.

Comment: The OP should worry about `INT_MIN / -1` as well.  Both zero division and division overflow can cause abrupt program termination.

Answer (score 3):

There is no possibility for a division by `0` in your example, yet there is **another special case** you should check for: dividing `INT_MIN` by `-1` may cause a division overflow, and usually causes an fatal exception on Intel hardware, a surprising behavior, yet consistent with the C Standard that specifies that integer overflow can cause an implementation specific behavior.

If you need to protect against such unwanted behavior, you must special case these operands and handle them specifically:

```
#include <limits.h>

int foo(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return 0;
    if (a == INT_MIN && b == -1) return INT_MAX;
    return a / b;
}
```

Since the values of `a` and `b` can be crafted by an external source, you definitely need to worry about division overflow.  It is a fun game to play to try a crash unsafe calculators by feeding them these values.

Comment: That is only possible for 2s complement.

Comment: @Olaf: correct, but unlikely to save the OP ;-) . returning `INT_MAX` should be fine on the other architectures.

Comment: I actually recommended to either saturate or use an application-level "trap"/error representation. On 2s complement, `INT_MIN` would be a good choice, which automatically avoids the problem you pointed out. But then the code should use fault propagation. (Note that with gcc you are on the safe side, as it only supports 2s complement targets).